# How replace null value with {} in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to fetch value from table where null status value should get replace with {}(empty json object), so that I have used below mysql function

```
IFNULL(status, '{}') as status from table;
```

but its output is  `'{}'` but I want output as only `{}` (without single quotes)

Also I have tried with below options as well

```
IFNULL(status, "{}") -->  output -"{}"
IFNULL(status, '{}') -->  output -'{}'
IFNULL(status, {}) -->  output -Mysql error`
```

Expected output is only empty j son object Please suggest any solution.

Comment: please share your table with some of its data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql is not supporting JSON_UNQUOTE function in case you are converting that mysql result into json object. so work around is to use **replace string function**(java or any other language) in your framework.

EX.

- String rs = str.replace(""{","{"); // Replace '"{' with '{'
- String rs = str.replace("}"","}"); // Replace '}"' with '}'

Answer (score 0):

Check the function [`JSON_UNQUOTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) :

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(IFNULL(status, "{}")) as status FROM table
```

Comment: How to replace null value with {} in mysql?                                                              
                                                                                                                        
 Above solution is not working with Json Object. For  "status"  key value is string. so after using above function(JSON_UNQUOTE) output is "{}" instead of {}.